# Android (Nexus 7) bypass swipe/notification screen

Tags: boot

I have fixed in-car install of a Nexus 7 (5.1.1) using Timur's kernel. For years this has been working fine - turn on ignition,and the tablet boots straight to the home screen (or last activity it was doing).

I only take the table out to charge every so often, I DO NOT alter settings - I'm happy with them.

Now, suddenly, the tablet boots to the Swipe/Notification screen - this is a royal p-i-t-a. If I don't react quickly enough the screen turns off and I have to take the tablet out of the dash in order to access the power button.

No updates have been applied to the tablet, I'm sure of it.

All accessibility options are turned off.

Noticed Security is set to swipe - but I haven't set this. How did I disable it?

Thanks

Not sure if this a coincidence, but only seemed to happen after I had changed the car battery....

Comment: Simply setting lockscreen security back to "none" should do. Also, you should always keep a BT keyboard paired to the device in the car, so you can wake up / manipulate the device handily without having to take it out.

Comment: Thanks Andy, but I don't have the option of "None"

Answer (score 1):

Solved it :

Switch to Guest User, click the icon in the top right of quick access notification panel, remove Guest user then : Settings | Security | Screen Lock - select "None" (This was previously missing)